# Set id for inputText in iterator

Tags: javascript, jsf, myfaces, trinidad

My goal is to set the focus to a specific inputText.

As there seems to be no way to do this automatically with an tr:inputText property, I try to use Javascript.

For `document.getElementById` I need the id of the rendered html `<input>`. I try to set this id to the correct index. However, it is rendered with the id `varFieldIterator:0:varField` where the number 0 comes from the iterator and is different depending on my start value selectionStart. If I start with selectionStart = 10, the 1st index for the textbox 10 is 0. If I start with 15 and then have a PPR to show the first 15 textboxes, they get the id starting with 16.

I think the code will make clear what I try to achieve:

```
<tr:iterator
    id="varFieldIterator"
    value="#{myController.form.model.fieldList}"
    var="field"
    rows="15"
    first="#{{myController.form.model.selectionStart}"
    varStatus="status">
  <tr:inputText
      id="varField#{status.index}"
      value="#{field.value}"
      label="Text #{status.index +1}">
</tr:iterator>

<tr:inputHidden
    id="FOCUS_TEXT"
    value="#{myController.form.model.endFocus}"></tr:inputHidden>
<trh:script>
window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('varField' + document.getElementById('FOCUS_TEXT').value).focus(); } 
</trh:script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the ID attribute accepts EL expressions, it is only set during view build time, not during view render time. So if you were using a view build time tag such as JSTL `<c:forEach>` it would have worked. But this tag may have [undesireable side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense).

I'd recommend to just change your JavaScript function so that it does not depend on IDs anymore. It's unclear what your entire HTML dom structure is and if you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or not which would simplify HTML DOM traversal.

With plain JS, you could for example just [grab the first form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms) and then grab its first input element:

```
document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
```

Or you could [grab input elements by tag name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus();
```

Or you could give them all a class name like `<tr:inputText styleClass="specificInput">` and [grab them by class name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("specificInput")[0].focus();
```

Those calls are chainable. So if you know that it's inside a `<h:form id="myForm">` then you could also do for example:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus();
```

Comment: While the easy solution to set an id independent of the iterator's numbers did not work, your suggestion nevertheless helped to find a workaround.